# using mysql to track sessions instead of trusting the server?

Tags: php, mysql

Some context...skip to the bottom for question if you are impatient...

I am trying to limit access to four pages on my (future) website to users with a valid username and password pair. To this end, I have a simple PHP/HTML form...in my PHP/HTML form the client types in a username and password, hits 'submit'...the data goes to POST and another PHP script validates the user/passwd pair by using a SELECT in my mySQL database...

userpassword table:
uid (PRIMARY KEY,INT), username (varchar 32), password (char 128)

If the match works then it looks up the access table to see what page that particular username has access to (1 for access, 0 for no access):

useraccess table:
uid (PRIMARY KEY,INT), securename0(TINYINT), securepage1(TINYINT)...

The PHP script then prints out links to the secure pages they have access to. If I understand them correctly, the articles and books I have read state that you normally store a cookie on the client side with a session ID that points to a session file on server that stores the username/password pair and whatever other session variables until it either times out or the user logs out.

I don't want to spend the money for a dedicated server. So all that PHP session info is saved all lumped together on the server, along with the other half dozen websites from other customers running on it. This strikes me as horribly insecure...

**The *question* is...would it be any more secure to circumvent all that and store/track the per-user session information in my own mySQL table?** ie. something like this:

session table:
sessionkey (PRIMARYKEY, CHAR(128)), uid(INT), expiretimedate(DATETIME), accesstosecurepage0 (TINYINT), accesstosecurepage1(TINYINT)...

So when a user hits any "secure" page it would check their session id cookie (if present) and then do a SELECT on the session table to see if that particular "sessionkey" is present, then give them access depending on what accesstosecurepage0,1,2,etc. are set to.

Would this work better than the alternative or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Hm, that's not the only reason why shared hosting is not very "secure". In many cases the servers are not properly secured against privilege escalation or unauthorized file access (like reading database configuration files from other customers). Maybe a VServer is an option if you don't want to spend a lot of money? In Germany, those can be had for a few euros a month.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this making your application any more secure. Session hijacking occurs when someone retrieves another user's session ID and pretends to be them. Your session table would not prevent this from happening. (I skipped to the bottom btw, hope I didn't miss any important details:)

It might even make it less secure since you are now giving hijackers two ways to steal session data: One through the file system and one through the DB. As to which one is more secure over the other, I'm not too sure, but I would think it depends on well you secure either one yourself.

Comment: BUT the temp files used to store the sessions usually rest unencrypted and with `o+r` permissions in shared hosting environments. In so far, it might be a little bit more secure to save the sessions in the DB instead.

Comment: They should not rest unencrypted o_O

Comment: I concurr. the storage location of the session data isnt any more or less secure (assuming the server filesystem and db are secure). It does have other benefits though, like if youre running multiple web servers but need session stuff to be consistent across all.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Usually the database is much better configured than the filesystem (probably because it requires less knowledge to do it ;). What's worse, while you can usually tweak the reading permissions on your own files (like PHP scripts, configuration files etc.), you often don't have access to the php.ini itself to tweak the location or permissions of your session data.

Comment: @NiklasB. Another thing to consider is that there is a lot of code out there that doesn't protect against sql injection attacks. A database is only secure as the data access code. In that sense, it could be less secure.

Comment: @Shredder: No, if someone gets hold of your DB, you are screwed anyway. The point that's important here is that MySQL server configurations are usually Good Enough (in the sense that one user cannot read or write data from other users), while filesystem permissions are usually horrendously misconfigured (to the point where you can read the whole server filesystem as a customer).

Comment: @NiklasB. "if someone gets hold of your DB, you are screwed anyway" Tuche.. Could you show me an example of how to access and read a poorly misconfigured server file?

Comment: @Shredder: I've seen plenty (I work as a penetration tester). Usually in shared hosting, if `open_basedir` is actually used at all, it's either misconfigured to allow access to the whole www-root (including all other customer  sites) or you can work around it using `system` and the alikes or by using misconfigured features like `ExecCGI` or server side includes or even by exploiting the Linux kernel (which is, as you might have guessed, often outdated). But in most cases, you can simply read from `/etc/passwd` directly from PHP without any problems.

Comment: @Nkilas: And this is why you cant beat a $20 VPS and a few hours a month for a sysadmin setup and manage your images if you dont know *nix security.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Don't tell me. But actually virtualization is quite effective for security, so virtual servers are usually a lot cheaper than dedicated systems while still vastly more secure than shared hosting (at least if the admins have a tiny bit of basic understanding of networking)

Answer (score 1):

This question is about as old as sessions themselves, although possibly for slightly different reasons than yours. Security is not the issue, as session hijacking occurs when someone gets hold of a user's session ID and sends that to the server. Therefore, using a database to store session data is as insecure as using a file on the machine - it essentially amounts to the same thing.

Database sessions tend to be used when multiple servers are required to host one site, or sessions need to be stored across different but related domains. However, it is considerably more work to set this up from scratch, if not using a pre-built framework.

If you don't need this functionality then using the standard session should be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

*Potentially* more secure, yes -- after all, shared hosting is an infamous target for exactly the kind of security breaches you fear but, once again, the MySQL server is shared and accessible by other users just like all other resources so, worst case scenario, the damage is exactly the same.

The efficiency hit, however, would probably be unbearable and would almost certainly mitigate the extra peace of mind. To avoid the use of sessions or similar mechanisms completely, you wouldn't even have an easy way to cache the db results and a query per page load, per person - an *unnecessary* query - may well prove unacceptable.

Not to mention, you're replacing one class of vulnerability with a whole new one in the form of SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah, but the default configuration of DB servers is usually better than the one of filesystem permissions (which requires additional knowledge and tweaking that is often lacking)

Comment: That's the only reason I even gave it "potentially more" and the drawbacks are just too weighty for the tentative benefits. The problem is that by the time you're in the position to actually *do* something about the relative securities of the db vs standard filesystem yourself, you could've just worked at making the filesystem watertight in the first place

Comment: To summarise for the purpose of answering the question: any difference in security between the 2 methods is vastly down to your host and, unless you know them especially well, that makes the whole thing a cumbersome, time-consuming leap of faith. Hard to recommend it.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to speak of "security" in the context of shared hosting.